# email address in Angular i18n string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, internationalization, mailto

I'm adding a internationalized message to the footer of an AngularJS page, including an email address - For additional help, please send an email to help@email.com
This is added to the relevant js i18n files as

```
"helpnote": "For additional help, please send an email to mailto:help@email.com"
"helpnote": "Para obtener ayuda adicional, por favor envíe un correo electrónico a mailto:help@email.com"
"helpnote": "Pour une aide supplémentaire, se il vous plaît envoyez un courriel à mailto:help@email.com"
```

etc

unfortunately the mailto link appears as text if I use

```
 <div class="helpnote">{{i18n.helpnote}}</div>
```

i.e. this exact string appears on screen - "For additional help, please send an email to mailto:help@email.com"

Can the internationalized string be written, or bound to the div, in such a way that the link becomes active?

Comment: for link html markup mb you need to use smth like:[ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) or a custom filter, when using angular expression or ng-bing; as for *internationalized string* - you get the right string from i18n or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either ng-click on the div to make it avtive somehow and do the redirection in the controller using $location perhaps ( if there is more magic behind your action ) or simply create regular link with ng-href.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: Thanks, I did soemthing like this. I've separated the string into two parts. The intenationalised part is now just "For additional help, please send an email to" and the email address is a $rootScope variable, with <a ng-href="{{helpEmail}}">{{helpEmail}}</a> to display it.
This makes more sense, if we change the email address, I only have to make one change, instead of to each i18n file